# When Log4cxx write the logs into file?

Tags: c++, logging, rollingfileappender, log4cxx

When Log4cxx decides to write the logs it caches into the file (as configured previously), is it buffer based or timer based?

Also, can I configure Log4cxx to write the logs when I send the logs to it not when it decides to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set your file in the [`RollingfileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/apidocs/classlog4cxx_1_1_rolling_file_appender.html) with [`setfile()`](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/apidocs/classlog4cxx_1_1_file_appender.html#aa4a716f4661cf85cdfde59b447654358) you can tell whether you want buffered IO or not.  This option will automatically configure [`setImmediateFlush()`](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/apidocs/classlog4cxx_1_1_writer_appender.html#a58ab91de34ae4ce9b59c62695ec4fc31) accordingly.

The code for the buffered writter shows that the flushing decistion is taken based on the size exclusively (if the buffer+new output exceeds bufer size).

Comment: could you explain more? for example, when Log4cxx get the timestamp of a log?